# Migrating from TYPO3_DB

Tags: php, typo3-9.x

I migrated my website to TYPO3 9x. but after migration I get an error in one of the extension :

`Call to a member function sql_num_rows() on null` in this line :

```
if($GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_num_rows($res)){
    while($CATEGORY = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $uids[] = $CATEGORY['uid'];
    }
}
```

According to this link I will need to change the code structure :

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Migration/Index.html#result-set-iteration

So I changed the code like that :

```
if($statement = $queryBuilder->execute()){
while ($category = $statement->fetch()) {
    $uids[] = $category['uid'];
}
}
```

But i still get the error `Call to a member function execute() on null`

Please how to change my code to make it works ?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you did not say anything about the preparations for this code. maybe you missed something.
Here an example of an extension:

```
$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
$queryBuilder = $connection->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_myext_domain_model_myrecords');
$queryBuilder->select('uid', 'titel')
            ->from('tx_myext_domain_model_myrecords')
            ->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->like('title',   $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($searchWord)),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->like('content', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($searchWord))
                ));
```

only then there is a

```
$statement = $queryBuilder->execute();
```

This code might vary slightly from code for TYPO3 8.

Comment: This is the preparations  `$res = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
  $res->setRestrictions(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendRestrictionContainer::class));
  $res->select($select)
     ->from($table)
     ->where(
     $where
  )
   ->execute()
   ->fetchAll();`